# How to play video in AR core in android with rotate, scale and zoom?

Tags: android, arcore

I want to play video in AR core android on surface detect. We able to load model but want to play video.

Comment: Well this is what you want. Now lets see some code and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Yeah, this is possible, what difficult are you confronting now?